# Python - Buscar cadena que cumpla el formato: Número entre 0 y 9 + texto

Tags: python, python-2.7, string, if, búsquedas

Quiero realizar en Python 2.7 una búsqueda en cadena con el siguiente formato:
Cualquier número entre 0 y 9 + " years"

He pensado algo así:

```
if (variable.find([0-9]+" years") < 0):
```

Por ejemplo, se cumple si la cadena contiene: 3 years

Por ejemplo, se cumple si la cadena contiene: 5 years

Por ejemplo, se cumple si la cadena contiene: 9 years

Por ejemplo, NO se cumple si la cadena contiene: Z years

Por ejemplo, NO se cumple si la cadena contiene: years

...

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

En vez de aplicar `str.find` sobre la cadena con todas las posibilidades válidas de forma iterativa (lo cual puede ser impracticable), puedes usar [expresiones regulares](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Un ejemplo simple puede ser:

```
import re



cadenas  =("He is 3 years old", 
           "9 years", 
           "He is 10 years old", 
           "He is z years old", 
           "He is years old", 
           "5 years!", 
           "5 yearsss", 
           "a5 years")

patt = re.compile(r"\b[1-9] years\b")

for cad in cadenas:
    if patt.search(cad):
        print(cad)
```

Lo cual nos muestra (cadenas que valida):

> He is 3 years old
>   9 years old
>   5 years!

La expresión regular en este caso es `"\b[1-9] years\b"`, donde:

- `\b` es conocido como ["word boundary"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) y es un ancla que indica que la coincidencia se debe producir en un límite de palabras.
- `[0-9]` busca un carácter que esté en el rango 0-9.

Puedes modificar la expresión de acuerdo a tus requerimientos, como permitir cualquier numero de espacios entre el dígito y la palabra, buscar un digito seguido de una palabra cualquiera, que valide "year" y "years", etc.

Comment: He probado tu solución y funciona. El problema es que tengo un fichero de varios miles de líneas y como bien decías, "lo cual puede ser impracticable" ¡el tiempo de ejecución aumenta una barbaridad! Finalmente he tenido que buscar otra solución alternativa... pero igualmente gracias por tu contribución.